# How to set a background for all view controllers?

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

I would like to give the user the option to select which background image they would like to have in the navigation controller. After the user selecting the background image, how can I embed or set that background image permanently for each view Controller as I keep creating one? For example, I would like to provide different backgrounds as options, such as a beach environment picture, how can I embed or set all view controllers to have a beach environment background?

Answer (score 0):

So your app already contains all the choices right?

Just make the one they selected into a property. It's very easy to later properties in iOS. You can read about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Then when your app loads, just get the name of the chosen image and set it to the background.